# Hbase 'table_attr' command

Tags: hbase

What is the difference between the two command in Hbase:

alter ‘t1′, METHOD => ‘table_att’, MAX_FILESIZE => ‘134217728

alter ‘t1′,  MAX_FILESIZE => ‘134217728

I know that both will alter the column family to 128MB.

could anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Good question.

They are similar. I think the format `METHOD => 'table_att'` is deprecated.

You can check it in the [sourcecode of the alter shell command](https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=hbase.git;a=blob;f=hbase-shell/src/main/ruby/hbase/admin.rb;h=532f073484fc85d6724696b22d552e5b5e6209c1;hb=refs/heads/master#l499).